# How to encrypt the Raspbian installation

Tags: raspbian, partition

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi. I just bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and installed on a different SD card the lite version of Raspbian Stretch. But now I need to encrypt the whole partition. I want to run a system which will use databases and files with very sensitive data and its a very big risk if someone take the SD card and reads the file system.

So how can I encrypt the whole partition? I know I can do it in Ubuntu, so I should be able to do it in Raspbian as well... Any help, even if it's little will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think that you need to ask your question on a linux site

Comment: No, because in Ubuntu this is not an issue, this is raspbian specific

Comment: What do you do on ubuntu? It shouldn't be much different... And raspbian is based off of Debian linux, so asking this on a linux site probably _would_ be a good idea.

Comment: `i know i can do it in ubuntu` - have you tried doing the same *thing* you know in raspbian?

Comment: When on ubuntu install you get the option to encrypt your system, but as we all know, raspbian doesnt have an installer, you just load the image into the sdcard and it run by  itself... and as scitronboy said, raspbian its based on Debian, so it should be possible but i don't have a clue to work on